# Adjust tslint condition for max-length limit

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, tslint

At our workplace, we use tslint to maintain similar code structure.
Our tslint includes rule like this:

```
"max-line-length": [
    true,
    120
],
```

which enforces (gives warning if not followed) to complete a line within 120 characters.
But, many times, with long functions, we have multiple conditions and code goes under tab after tab.

So, the problem is: Even if I start a line from 110th character space and write more than 10 characters, it shows me warning.

Is there anyway, I can change the tslint.json, so that it counts the length from first non-empty character or something like that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like ignoring whitespace wouldn't meet the spirit of the rule - the point of limiting line length is to allow code to be viewed e.g. on smaller screens or side-by-side without having to scroll horizontally. I doubt that would be an option, therefore. A better fix might be to refactor to more shorter, *narrower* functions.

Comment: Just put an `enter` at a meaningful place will solve this issue. If possible just give us a sample line of code.

Comment: But.. putting an enter after every 10 characters will not make a pleasant, readable code. Even if I need to write `let newVariable = "newValue"`, requires far more than 10 characters. @SRana

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I understand, the sole purpose of tslint is to make us write shorter, narrower functions. But, in an industrial project, similar to ours, we cannot refactor the whole code, which is there already, moreover tslint provides flexibility in rules as per our requirement. So, I here want to know : How to edit a rule in tslint ?

Comment: No, that's not its sole purpose. You can see the rule config in the docs: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/max-line-length/. It doesn't supporting excluding whitespace, as far as I can see, so if your constraints prevent changing the actual length of the lines you either have to increase the limit or disable the rule.

Comment: @KevalBhogayata, you don't need to put an enter on every 10 characters, you have to put at somewhere close 120 charter. Or add this line to ignore the warning // tslint:disable: max-line-length

Comment: @SRana, I know the concept of 120 characters.. but as I said, in question, what if my line starts from 110th characater itself..due to tabs in a long function ?